# Unity 5.3.5 - Blurry UI text after switching canvasses - until text is refreshed by turning visibility off/on or changing resolution

Tags: unity, gui, text

I have multiple scenes in my project where the canvas are switched between, each canvas having UI text included on it.

The project was originally created in version 5.0 and I have just updated to version 5.3.5 and I am now encountering the following issue -

The canvas that is active when the scene first loads displays all UI text just fine, but as soon as I switch to another canvas with the exact same text on, the text on the new canvas is blurred. As soon as I turn the text object off/on (via a button click) it appears to refresh it and it all displays fine again.  It is also rectified by changing the display resolution in the editor play window.

It appears as though unless it has a 'refresh' through clicking something else, or is on screen when the scene first loads, it appears blurry.

The font is 'Open Sans Bold' and I am switching canvasses via a raycast script.

I have read issues of text blurriness in 5.3, but most instances appear to be down to the size of the text being in odd numbers which mine isn't.

Screenshots attached. The settings shown are the same for all canvasses and text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]